# How to plot conditional colored outlines of barplots according to some variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, colorbar, geom-col

I have the following data

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
"2020"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), station = c("41B001", 
"41B011_41R012", "41B001", "41B011_41R012", "41B001", "41B011_41R012", 
"41B001", "41B011_41R012", "41B001", "41B011_41R012", "41B001", 
"41B011_41R012", "41B001", "41B011_41R012", "41B001", "41B011_41R012", 
"41B001", "41B011_41R012", "41B001", "41B011_41R012"), concentration = c(NA, 
26.7276362390038, NA, 25.6793849658314, NA, 26.4231406374957, 
NA, 22.318982275586, NA, 22.0774877184965, NA, 21.6359649122807, 
56.1669215086646, 21.6140621430203, 56.1504197761194, 19.7031357486815, 
51.5015359168242, 17.0787333944114, 36.3595993515516, 11.4634841061866
), yield = c(0, 99.9200913242009, 0, 99.9544626593807, 0, 99.9200913242009, 
0, 99.8287671232877, 0, 99.9200913242009, 6.65983606557377, 99.931693989071, 
89.5890410958904, 99.9315068493151, 97.8995433789954, 99.5662100456621, 
96.62100456621, 99.6803652968037, 98.3151183970856, 99.9203096539162
), environ = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Urbain avec très faible influence du trafic", 
"Urbain avec très forte influence du trafic"), class = "factor"), 
    environ_station = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Urbain avec très faible influence du trafic (41B011, 41R012)", 
    "Urbain avec très forte influence du trafic (41B001)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It is plotted with the following code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = concentration, fill = environ_station)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.75, colour = ifelse(round(data$yield, 0) < 85, "red", "black"), size = 0.5, position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 40), linetype = 'dashed', colour = 'red', size = 1) +
  labs(x = '', y = label_conc) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.margin=margin(l = -2, unit='line'),
                          legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
                          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10), 
                          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

as this figure [image: figure]

However, the resulting outlines of the bars up to 2016 are drawn in red, while they are expected to be black since their yield is above 85. It seems that missing bars (with concentration = NA) from the second class is causing the issue (order mixup).

Any idea on how to fix this, please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you set the border colors via the color argument. To solve your issue set the color conditionally inside `aes()` and make use of `scale_color_manual` as I did in my approach below or make use of `scale_color_identity`.

Note: I dropped the resulting color legend via `guides`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = concentration, fill = environ_station)) +
  geom_col(aes(colour = ifelse(round(yield, 0) < 85, "red", "black")), width = 0.75, 
           size = 0.5, position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red", black = "black")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2), color = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 40), linetype = 'dashed', colour = 'red', size = 1) +
  #labs(x = '', y = label_conc) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.margin=margin(l = -2, unit='line'),
                          legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
                          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10), 
                          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

[image]

Comment: Slight modification to this solution because if the fill variable can take more than 2 different values, the bars will be ordered according to the colour variable and then to the fill variable which can result in different orders for each year. A solution is to move to colour aesthetic with the fill aesthetic in ggplot call:
`ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = concentration, fill = environ_station, colour = ifelse(round(yield, 0) < 85, "red", "black"))) + geom_col(width = 0.75, size = 0.5, position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + ...`